# Clean Data Using SQL - Take Column Difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, derived-table

I have data in SQL as follows:

**Actual Table**

```
+-------------+--------+------+
|     Id      | Weight | Type |
+-------------+--------+------+
| 00011223344 |     35 | A    |
| 00011223344 |     10 | A    |
| 12311223344 |    100 | B    |
| 00034343434 |     25 | A    |
| 00034343434 |     25 | A    |
| 99934343434 |    200 | C    |
| 88855667788 |    100 | D    |
+-------------+--------+------+
```

Column `ID` will always have length of 11 and has data type varchar. I need to create a column `Actual Weight` and `Actual ID` from the table above.

`Actual Id` is dependent on column `ID`. If the ID starts with `000` than we need to find ID from column `ID` that does not starts with `000` but characters after that (i.e. 8 characters from right) are similar. Matched ID would be the `Actual Id`. For example if we look at first 3 ids first 2 starts with `000` and another ID that does not starts with `000` and contains similar 8 characters from right can be found in 3rd row i.e. `12311223344` therefore in derived column `Actual ID` the first 2 rows would have `Actual Id` as `12311223344`.

`Actual Weight` is dependent on values in 2 columns `ID` and `Weight`. We need to group column `Id` based on the criteria mentioned above if for any `Id` that does not starts with `000` but contains another entry that does starts with `000`. Then we need to recalculate `Weight` for `Id` that does not starts with `000` by adding all Weights of ones starting with `000` and taking difference with one that does not starts with `000`.

Example if we look at first 3 rows, in 3rd row we have `Id` starting with `123` and having entries that have 8 digits from right similar to this one except they start with `000` instead of `123` (i.e. row 1 and 2). For cases starting with `000` `Actual Weight` would be similar to `Weight` but for the one starting with `123` `Actual Weight` would be `100-(35+10)`

I am looking for a query that can create these 2 derived column without need of creating any other table/view.

**Desired Output**

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+------+
|     Id      |  Actual ID  | Weight | Actual Weight | Type |
+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+------+
| 00011223344 | 12311223344 |     35 |            35 | A    |
| 00011223344 | 12311223344 |     10 |            10 | A    |
| 12311223344 | 12311223344 |    100 |            55 | B    |
| 00034343434 | 99934343434 |     25 |            25 | A    |
| 00034343434 | 99934343434 |     25 |            25 | A    |
| 99934343434 | 99934343434 |    200 |           150 | C    |
| 88855667788 | 88855667788 |    100 |           100 | D    |
+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+------+
```

Comment: What would happen if you had an additional row with id 45611223344?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis that would never happen this ID is unique.

Comment: Just by the way: if `ID` is *always* 11 characters it should probably be `char(11)` not `varchar(11)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . If I'm following this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when id like '000%' then weight
             else weight - sum(case when id like '000%' then weight else 0 end) over (partition by actual_id)
        end) as actual_weight
from (select t.*,
             max(id) over (partition by stuff(id, 1, 3, '')) as actual_id
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4f6856656910b1a81f001c912d19fb39) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: can you please suggest how can I add another column to get the `Type` that was against the `actual_id` i.e. for 1st two rows I want type to be `B` instead of `A` that was against the `actual_id` `12311223344`

Comment: @Lopez . . . Can you ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results?

Comment: I've asked question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920136/derive-column-by-finding-unique-string-from-column-in-a-subset with desired output.