# Derive Column By Finding Unique String From Column in a Subset

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, derived-table

The idea behind this question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870191/clean-data-using-sql-take-column-difference?noredirect=1#comment118206948_66870191) with a slight change. Consider data below

**Actual Output**

```
+-------------+--------+------+
|     Id      | Weight | Type |
+-------------+--------+------+
| 00011223344 |     35 | A    |
| 00011223344 |     10 | A    |
| 12311223344 |    100 | B    |
| 00034343434 |     25 | A    |
| 00034343434 |     25 | A    |
| 99934343434 |    200 | C    |
| 88855667788 |    100 | D    |
+-------------+--------+------+
```

**Derived Output**

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+------+
|     Id      |  Actual ID  | Weight | Actual Weight | Type |
+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+------+
| 00011223344 | 12311223344 |     35 |            35 | A    |
| 00011223344 | 12311223344 |     10 |            10 | A    |
| 12311223344 | 12311223344 |    100 |            55 | B    |
| 00034343434 | 99934343434 |     25 |            25 | A    |
| 00034343434 | 99934343434 |     25 |            25 | A    |
| 99934343434 | 99934343434 |    200 |           150 | C    |
| 88855667788 | 88855667788 |    100 |           100 | D    |
+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+------+
```

I need to add another column to table above to add `Actual_Type` against column type. Above table can be derived by following code also provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870191/clean-data-using-sql-take-column-difference?noredirect=1#comment118206948_66870191).

```
select t.*,
       (case when id like '000%' then weight
             else weight - sum(case when id like '000%' then weight else 0 end) over (partition by actual_id)
        end) as actual_weight
from (select t.*,
             max(id) over (partition by stuff(id, 1, 3, '')) as actual_id
      from t
     ) t;
```

I can't think of how can I apply partition by and apply max on a column Type that is varchar.

**Desired Output**

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+------+-------------+
|     Id      |  Actual ID  | Weight | Actual Weight | Type | Actual Type |   
+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+------+-------------+
| 00011223344 | 12311223344 |     35 |            35 |  A   | B           |   
| 00011223344 | 12311223344 |     10 |            10 |  A   | B           |   
| 12311223344 | 12311223344 |    100 |            55 |  B   | B           |   
| 00034343434 | 99934343434 |     25 |            25 |  A   | C           |   
| 00034343434 | 99934343434 |     25 |            25 |  A   | C           |   
| 99934343434 | 99934343434 |    200 |           150 |  C   | C           |
| 88855667788 | 88855667788 |    100 |           100 |  D   | D           |
+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+------+-------------+
```

**Edit:**
I can not apply `min` or `max` over column `Type` which is `nvarchar`. I want to partition over column `Actual ID` and find the value which is unique in column `Type` i.e. `B` for 1st 3 rows. For next 3 it is C.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve beyond "I want this to look like that."?

Comment: *I can not apply min or max over column Type which is nvarchar* why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Weight, t.Type, t.actual_id, t.actual_weight,
       FIRST_VALUE(Type) OVER (PARTITION BY actual_id ORDER BY counter) AS actual_type
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE 
           WHEN id like '000%' THEN weight
           ELSE weight - SUM(CASE WHEN id LIKE '000%' THEN WEIGHT ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY actual_id)
         END AS actual_weight,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY actual_id, Type) counter
  FROM (
    SELECT t.*,  MAX(id) OVER (PARTITION BY STUFF(id, 1, 3, '')) AS actual_id
    FROM t
  ) t
) t;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4b15b7c38c3a6820ec2afade5d1ac283).

Answer (score 0):

I have added another column in your original query with the same partition logic you are using to create actual_id column.

Schema:

```
  create table t (ID varchar(20), Weight int , Type varchar(20));
  insert into t values( '00011223344' ,     35 , 'A');    
  insert into t values( '00011223344' ,     10 , 'A');    
  insert into t values('12311223344' ,    100 , 'B');    
  insert into t values('00034343434' ,     25 , 'A');    
  insert into t values('00034343434' ,     25 , 'A');    
  insert into t values('99934343434' ,    200 , 'C');    
  insert into t values('88855667788' ,    100 , 'D');
```

Query:

```
 select t.*,
        (case when id like '000%' then weight
              else weight - sum(case when id like '000%' then weight else 0 end) over (partition by actual_id)
         end) as actual_weight,
         max(type)over (partition by stuff(id, 1, 3, ''))
          
 from (select t.*,
              max(id) over (partition by stuff(id, 1, 3, '')) as actual_id
       from t
      ) t;
```

Output:

| ID | Weight | Type | actual_id | actual_weight | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00011223344 | 35 | A | 12311223344 | 35 | B |
| 00011223344 | 10 | A | 12311223344 | 10 | B |
| 12311223344 | 100 | B | 12311223344 | 55 | B |
| 00034343434 | 25 | A | 99934343434 | 25 | C |
| 00034343434 | 25 | A | 99934343434 | 25 | C |
| 99934343434 | 200 | C | 99934343434 | 150 | C |
| 88855667788 | 100 | D | 88855667788 | 100 | D |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1aedd02c1c7e013cfd7b2672c668a7a6)*

Comment: I've rectified the output in edit. Also I am a bit skeptical using `min` or `max` on a column that is of type `nvarchar `

Comment: Would you prefer order by over max()?

Comment: I believe using `min` `max` creates dependency on alphabetical order of column Type assuming you replaced `Type` for first two rows as `B` and third row as `A` the actual ID would be `B` instead of `A`